# using sed substitute with a bash variable

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to:

```
sed -i s/installpath/"$INSTALL_PATH"/ /tmp/myscript.conf
```

when $INSTALL_PATH is just a string everything works. but if install path is an actual path (II guess the '/' char is the problem) like /home/ubuntu/install_script. then It breaks with the following error message:

> > sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unknown option to `s'

btw: I tried without the "" around $INSTALL_PATH. didn't work

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that `$INSTALL_PATH` contains slashes, which means that they will be interpreted by sed as part of the `s/pattern/replacement/` construct. To avoid this, you should use a different separator, for example `~`:

```
sed -i "s~installpath~$INSTALL_PATH~" /tmp/myscript.conf
```

I have also wrapped the whole sed line in quotes rather than quoting one section. In general, it's a good idea to do this as it prevents other characters from being interpreted by the shell. Normally single quotes are used but if shell variables are to be expanded, use double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use `/` as the delimiter in sed commands.  Use something that's less likely to occur in a filename, e.g.:

```
sed -i s^installpath^"$INSTALL_PATH"^ /tmp/myscript.conf
```

If you're careful with quoting you can use other characters which are even less likely to exist inside a filename:

```
sed -i "s|installpath|$INSTALL_PATH|" /tmp/myscript.conf
```

The pipe is outright illegal in Windows paths, and on Linux it's a really bad idea and unlikely to occur in the wild.